# "ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets" is not working for javascript file. Do I need to configure something else than just installing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I was editing a javascript file, and when I wrote: `p{Hello}` I expected it to convert into `<p>Hello</p>` .But it doesn't seem to happen. Is there anything else I need to do to configure this extension in VS Code to make it work? The code is given below.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

const ArrowHeader = () => {
  return(
    p{Hello}
  )
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello Scaler</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Remember the more data u give more help could arrive, and try to make ur question searchable, right now ur title is not good for ur content because its too broad.

Comment: thankyou, i will surely keep this in mind from now.

Answer (score 1):

p{Hello} is not a component.
if you want to display `<p>Hello</p>`, you need to create a custom component.

Comment: no, actually i was trying to use snippets, i.e., I wanted p{Hello} to convert into <p>Hello</p> on pressing the enter key. But its not happening so I thought there is some configuration error with my ES7 extension for VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is not with the ES7 extension, but emmet was not configured with javascript files, it works fine after adding javascript as a language for emmet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

-Try adding this to your settings.json file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    }
```

-If you don't want that configuration, you can manually change it to each file Language Mode to JavaScript React:

1. With the .js file open click on the Language Mode Selector:
   [Language Mode Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIpko.png)
2. Search for JavaScript React (or JSX): [Select JavaScript React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDNEA.png)
3. Check if it applied correctly: [JSX Mode applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUXbv.png)